# Gazebo Kinect Plugin Point Transformation for RayShape

Tags: transform, ros, kinect, point-clouds, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to simulate a stackingbox with some elements and create a PointCloud with the kinect camera and now im trying to label these points with the ids of the elements with an rayshape

The cam is at "0.0 0.0 1.9 0.0 1.5707963267948966 0.0" so i tried to transfrom the frame with `<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_broadcaster" args="0.0 0.0 1.9 0.0 1.5707963267948966 0.0 map depth_camera_link" />`

but than the map frame is not at (0,0,0)

[image]

when I use

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_broadcaster" args="0.0 0.0
-1.9 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000 map depth_camera_link" />
```

[image]

Then it is in the middle of the stackingbox where also the root point of the world is

But unfortunately the ray laser is not completely correct

[image]

I use in these example a banana as an element

Ray Code [here](https://github.com/kingingo/BinPickingSim/blob/main/src/gz_ray_label_plugin/src/gz_ray_label_plugin.cc)

My Source code [here](https://github.com/kingingo/BinPickingSim)

Edit:
Now, I found out that the frame is not completely correct ([HERE](https://answers.ros.org/question/232534/gazebo-camera-frame-is-inconsistent-with-rviz-opencv-convention/?answer=232562#post-id-232562))

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ime_slam_camera_tf" args="0 0 0 -1.57079632679 0 -1.57079632679 depth_camera_link kinect_optical_link 10"/>
 <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_broadcaster" args="0.0 0.0 1.9 0.0 1.5707963267948966 0.0 map depth_camera_link" />
```

So i have now the transformation chain map -> depth_camera_link -> kinect_optical_link and "kinect_optical_link" is now my direct camera frame

The map frame is on the correct position but the ray sensor is only half right

[image]

Comment: solution was to go deeper at the z axis and now the ray is finding all